# Which Rule engine to use?

Tags: drools, rules, rule-engine, business-rules

I have a requirement for handling multiple rules and select a value as per the matching criteria.

The rule could be

case-1

```
----------------------------------------
| A  | B  | C  | D  | priority | value |
----------------------------------------
| a1 | b1 |    | c1   |  1       | 250 |
----------------------------------------
|      | b2 | c2 | d2 |  3       | 200 |
----------------------------------------
| a3   | b3 | c3 | d3 |  2       | 100 |
----------------------------------------
```

As per the above defined rules, we look for highest number of matching criteria first, and select the value of that rule, (i.e rule with value "100")

case-2

```
----------------------------------------
| A  | B  | C  | D  | priority | value |
----------------------------------------
| a1 | b1 |    | c1 |  1       | 100   |
----------------------------------------
|    | b2 | c2 | d2 |  2       | 200   |
----------------------------------------
```

If two conflicting rules found with same number of matching criteria, then look for priority, and select rule with highest priority. In this case (Rule with value "100".

case-3

```
----------------------------------------
| A  | B  | C  | D  | priority | value |
----------------------------------------
| a1 | b1 |    | c1 |  3       | 100   |
----------------------------------------
|    | b2 | c2 | d2 |  2       | 200   |
----------------------------------------
| a3 | b3 | c3 | d3 |  1       | 300   |
----------------------------------------
| a4 | b4 | c4 | d4 |  1       | 400   |
----------------------------------------
```

In this case, if more than one rule with same number of matching criteria found and with same priority then select the rule with highest value (i.e Rule4 with value 400).

I know it looks very specific, but i tried to google but couldn't came across any rule engine which can be used in this case.
Please help me out with some pointers and ideas to start with.

Comment: I don't think that any search engine will find "best solution for user virtual's problem". OTOH, why do you think that some rule engine will not be capable of solving this simple problem? Therefore, the answer to your question is: any rule engine will do.

Comment: Agree with laune. Any rules engine should be fine in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have pointed out, any rule engine should do in your case. Since this seems at first glance to be a very lightweight use-case, you can use [Rulette](https://github.com/kislayverma/Rulette/wiki) to do this almost trivially (Disclosure - I am the author). You could define your rules, and then use the *getAllRules* API to get the list of applicable rules on which you could do min/max as required.

I am curious, though, to understand why you would want to define conflicting rules and then apply a "priority" on them?